# How can I randomise User Agent for file_get_html?

Tags: php, user-agent, simpledom

I'm scraping a website (nothing dodgy) with simple_html_dom and need to randomise my user agent.

Tried to multiple array content but keep getting the first one.

```
$opts = array(
     'http'=>array(
       'header'=>"User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11A465 Safari/9537.53\r\n"
     )
   );
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$html = file_get_html($webpage, false, $context);
```

Comment: If it's OK to scrape it and the site owners don't mind it, then you shouldn't need this ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code above your and use $header in opts

```
$headers = [
    'User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11A465 Safari/9537.53\r\n',
    'header 2',
    'header n'
];
$header = $headers[array_rand($headers)];
```